# Hide default icon menu hamburger button on Ionic Menu | Ionic 4

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, menu

I need to remove hamburger default icon menu on ionic menu. I've added custom menu and I need to remove default icon.

So my code:

```html
<ion-menu side="start">  
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-icon name="home" slot="start"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Home</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-icon name="person" slot="start"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Profile</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-icon name="chatbubbles" slot="start"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Messages</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-icon name="settings" slot="start"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Settings</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

My layout menu:

[image: Layout menu]

Html button code:

```html
<ion-header _ngcontent-yjt-c1="" role="banner" class="ios header-ios hydrated">
    <ion-toolbar _ngcontent-yjt-c1="" class="ios hydrated">
        <ion-buttons _ngcontent-yjt-c1="" slot="start" class="buttons-first-slot sc-ion-buttons-ios-h sc-ion-buttons-ios-s ios hydrated">
            <ion-menu-button _ngcontent-yjt-c1="" class="hydrated ios button ion-activatable ion-focusable"></ion-menu-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title _ngcontent-yjt-c1="" class="ios title-ios hydrated"></ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

I need to remove default icon inside circle. How to do to remove?

Comment: can you show us the html code of the menu icon you want to hide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try the following css rules?
Can you please check if they don't work if they get added to the css of the page you are viewing?

```css
ion-menu-button {
    display: none !important;
}
```

or

```css
ion-buttons {
    display: none !important;
}
```

or

```css
.button.ion-activatable.ion-focusable {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below styles in your app.scss file to hide the default menu button

```css
.bar-button-menutoggle {
  display: none !important;
}
```